# Python: pandas dataframe complex update condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes dfItemRatings and dfItemMode as below.

ItemID in dfItemRatings will always be unique

dfItemRatings:

```
ItemID ItemName ItemRating
A1     ItemA1   0
A2     ItemA2   0
B1     ItemB1   0
B2     ItemB2   0
B3     ItemB3   0
```

dfItemMode:

```
ParentID    ItemMode    ItemRating
A1          Paid        5
A1          Received    6
B1          Paid        10
B2          Paid        3
B2          Received    4
B3          Paid        1
B3          Received    2
B3          Paid        7
```

I want to update ItemRating column in dfItemRatings with below conditions

1. For each ItemID in dfItemRatings, find count of matching ParentID in dfItemMode

   For e.g. A1 = 2, B1 = 1, B2 = 2, B3 = 3
2. I want to update ratings only for those ParentID whose count == 2 and ItemMode = 'Paid'

So my final output should look like below

```
ItemID ItemName ItemRating
A1     ItemA1   5
A2     ItemA2   0
B1     ItemB1   0
B2     ItemB2   3
B3     ItemB3   0
```

As you can see only A1 and B2 has count == 2 in dfItemMode and out of those 2 records i want to select ItemRatings only with ItemMode = 'Paid'

My actual dataframes has more than 50000 records. so for loop on these dataframes will slow down the performance.
What is the fatest way to implement this with minimum for loop ?
May be using df.loc[] ?

Please advise.

Regards
Vipul

Comment: please check my answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used methods:

- We use `groupby.transform` 
  to create a mask for the ParentID column based on the number of times each item is repeated.
- `Series.isin` to create a mask for the ParentID based on matches ItemsID
- `Series.eq` 
  to create a boolean mask based on an equivalence.
- `Series.map` to map and update values

---

```
c1=dfItemMode.groupby('ParentID')['ParentID'].transform('size').eq(2)
c2=dfItemMode['ParentID'].isin(dfItemRatings['ItemID'])
c3=dfItemMode['ItemMode'].eq('Paid')

dfItemRatings['ItemRating']=( dfItemRatings['ItemID'].map( dfItemMode.loc[c1&c2&c3]
                                                                     .set_index('ParentID')['ItemRating'] )
                                                      .fillna(dfItemRatings['ItemRating']) )
print(dfItemRatings)
```

**Output**

```
  ItemID ItemName  ItemRating
0     A1   ItemA1         5.0
1     A2   ItemA2         0.0
2     B1   ItemB1         0.0
3     B2   ItemB2         3.0
4     B3   ItemB3         0.0
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. This fixed my issue

Comment: Hi ansev,

this has solved my problem, But like itemratings, i have total 4 columns to update in my dfItemRatings dataframe with same logic. I have implemented that for all 4 columns and it's working fine.

Now, i have almost 50000 records in my dataframe dfItemRatings which is taking almost 45 seconds to update all 50000 records. Is there any fastest way to do it ?